# Facebook App With Heroku

Tags: php, facebook, heroku, facebook-apps, heroku-toolbelt

I just created my first Facebook app and chose to use Heroku. I followed the instructions and downloaded the Heroku toolbelt.  By the way I am doing this in php.  The next step is to Log in and upload your SSH key by typing Heroku login and then my email and password...after i do, it does say Authentication succesful but unlike the example it doesn't create/ask me to create an ssh key.  If I move to the next step by trying to Fetch your app's source code by typing git clone git@heroku.com:***my heroku url thingy***.git -o heroku...when i do this shows this: fatal: destination path '***my heroku url thingy*** already exists and is not an empty directory...finally i have no idea where to start begin editing my app...there was a file created on my computer (windows)...so ya thanks

Comment: Did you check the folder it mentioned? Are there files in there?

Comment: Ok as an update, I found the folder named my heroku url thingy and it has an index.php which code looks like the facebook app but two things still dont work, the ssh key and now when i change it and push it doesn't work...

Comment: "doesn't work"? Are you getting some kind of error?

Comment: yes, error: "fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git"

Comment: Are you running that command from the folder with the index.php?

Comment: What are you doing to get the error? Do you open command prompt and type something? What directory is your prompt in when you type the command?

If you can step by step us through exactly what you have tried, it might be easier to figure out what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I finally fixed it...the command git clone git@heroku.com:my-heroku-thingy.git -o heroku didnt work...so I changed the directory (thanks for the answer) with cd my-heroku-thingy and then did the commit then push

Answer (score 1):

First go to the folder `c:/program files/heroku`, then use command

`rm -r myheroku url thingy`

this will delete your existing directory and files previously created

Comment: Then what would I do to push it?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to **Commit**
using Command

```
$ git commit -am "changed"
```

then **Push** using

```
$ git push
```